# How to choose number of neurons and hidden layers?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I followed this guy's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ8BIBpya2k) on YouTube. Following is the code that was used for classifying 0 to 9 handwritten digits from MNIST dataset. The dataset contains 70,000 images of 28 x 28. Here, 60,000 are used for training and 10,000 are used for testing.

```
# Create the model.
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# Flatten layer i.e. instead of 28 x 28 to 784 pixels
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

# These are two hidden layers with '128' neurons each and 'ReLU' is the activation fuction choosen for them.
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))

# This one is output layer for 10 classifications
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

# optimizer and loss functions
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

# Now, lets train the model.
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)
```

I don't understand a couple of things from this code:

- Where is the input layer?
- How are '128' neurons are chosen?
- And why use two hidden layers?